# Prevent Mobile Device Center from launching when connecting a device in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, pocket-pc

Is there a way to prevent Windows Mobile Device Center from opening when I connect my Pocket-PC to my computer?

I am running Windows 7.

Comment: have you tried the old SHIFT-trick? hold down SHIFT when connecting a device to a USB port, this should should skip any automatic action.

Comment: i need somthing that will work automatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A developer on xda-developers made a program called [HMDC](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=360163) which does exactly that.

Comment: cool program !!! exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

win key + r (eg start -> run) 
gpedit.msc
computer configuration -> administrative templates -> windows components -> AutoPlayPolicies

Comment: thank's for the help !!
but what next ?  how to setup that the mobile center dont
open when i connect the Pocket-PC ?