# Prevent Windows Mobile Device Center from opening when Pocket PC is connected to computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile

How do I prevent Windows Mobile Device Center from opening when I connect a Pocket PC device to a Windows 7 computer?  Is this behaving like ActiveSync on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

See: [Prevent Mobile Device Center from launching when connecting a device in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/87433/prevent-mobile-device-center-from-launching-when-connecting-a-device-in-windows-7)

The short answer seems to be kill the WMDC.exe process.